# redshift mysql migration using Python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Hi I am using the following script to migrate data from mysql to redshift.

```
mysql_table_name = 'clabDevelopment.KPI_kpireport'
mysql_cur = mysql_conn.cursor()
mysql_cur.execute('select * from %s where Date = "2018-01-01";' % mysql_table_name  )
description = mysql_cur.description
rows = mysql_cur.fetchall()

# Insert data into Redshift
redshift_table_name = 'kpi_kpireport'
redshift_cur = redshift_conn.cursor()
insert_template = 'insert into %s (%s) values %s;'
column_names = ', '.join([x[0] for x in description])
values = ', '.join(['(' + ','.join(map(str, x)) + ')' for x in rows])

redshift_cur.execute(insert_template % (redshift_table_name, column_names, values))
```

The mail issue that I am having is that when the values are blank:

```
values (241325,2018-01-01,None,,CHG,USA,N.
```

like between None and CHG there is " ,, " and it causes the program to fail.

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trackstarz\migration.py", line 20, in <module>
    redshift_cur.execute(insert_template % (redshift_table_name, column_names, values))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...re_Costs, FBA_Fee) values (241325,2018-01-01,None,,CHG,USA,N...
                                                             ^

[Finished in 2.0s]
```

Comment: unless you only have a handful of rows that method is going to be very slow. consider other routes such as AWS DMS

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method for loading data into Amazon Redshift is via the `COPY` command. This allows bulk data to be loaded in parallel across all nodes.

It is recommended *not* to use individual `INSERT` statements to load data. (`INSERT` is fine if you are selecting bulk data from another table.)

Therefore, I recommend that you modify your program to output a CSV file (or other supported format) and then load it with the COPY command. It will be a lot cleaner and easier to debug that way, too.